# Adjust the position of an arrow

Tags: pgfplots

As can be seen, the positioning of the arrow is incorrect. I can improve by indicating 7.95 instead of 8. Is there a more solid method ?

```
   \documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
   \usepackage{pgfplots}
   \pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
   \usetikzlibrary{arrows,decorations.markings}
   \usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
   \begin{document}
   \begin{tikzpicture}
      [extended line/.style={shorten >=-#1,shorten <=-#1},
       /pgf/declare function={f(\x)=6*\x;},
       /pgf/declare function={g(\x)=4*\x + 16;}]  
   \begin{axis}[
     restrict x to domain=-1:14, xmax=14, xmin=-1,
     restrict y to domain=-10:100, ymax=100, ymin=-10,
     x=1cm,
     y=0.1cm,
     axis x line=middle,
     axis y line=middle,
     major tick style=black,
     axis line style = very thick,
     tick align=outside,
     tickwidth=0.12cm,
     tick style=thick,
     grid=both,
     xtick={0,1,...,13},
     ytick={0,10,...,90},
     extra x ticks={-1,14},
     extra x tick label={\null},
     extra y ticks={-10,100},
     extra y tick label={\null},
     extra tick style={tick style={draw=none}},
     xlabel=$x$,ylabel=$y$,
     every axis x label/.style={
     at={(ticklabel* cs:1.01)},anchor=west},
     every axis y label/.style={
     at={(ticklabel* cs:1.01)}, anchor=south},
     x tick label style={
     /pgf/number format/1000 sep={},
     },
     y tick label style={
     /pgf/number format/1000 sep={},
     }, 
     samples=2000,
     axis on top=false,
     >=stealth]
     \addplot [very thick,domain=0:14] {f(x)};
     \addplot [very thick,domain=0:14] {g(x)};
     \addplot [very thick,domain=8:14,red] {f(x)};

     \draw[red,dashed,thick](8,0) -- (8,{f(8)}) -- (0,{f(8)});
     \draw[arrows={Bracket[reversed,line join=miter]->},red,very thick]
     (8,0) -- (14,0); 
     \node[below left=2pt] at (0,0) {0};
    \end{axis}                  
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: If you consider that "aligning the left part of the top of the bracket to the arrow end instead of the middle of its vertical segment" is a bug/misfeature, my opinion is that the cleanest way to proceed is to contact the authors of the arrows.meta package and to tell them to fix that or add an option to choose. Any other fix will be a dirty hack, I fear. Btw your example could be smaller, this would make it easier (and more likely) for people to help you.

Comment: Instead, you could use the tikz library decorations.markings, see section 51.5 of the latest manual (page 646, version 3.1.5a).

Comment: This is the default, correct behavior of arrows. Their tip touches the start/end, and this is what you are seeing here. You can use `\draw[arrows={Bracket[reversed,line join=miter]->},red,very thick,
  shorten <=-2pt]
     (8,0) -- (14,0);`, perhaps this is what you are looking for.

Comment: This simple solution meets my expectations, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth]
\draw[help lines] grid (4,2);
\draw[arrows={Bracket[reversed,line join=miter]->},red,very thick] (1,2) -- (3,2); % initial example
\draw[postaction={decorate},red,very thick, decoration={
markings,% switch on markings
mark=at position -0.001cm with {\arrow[red,very thick]{>}},
mark=at position 0pt with {\arrow[red,very thick]{Bracket[]}}
}] (1,1) -- (3,1); % all purpose solution
\draw[postaction={decorate},red,very thick,decoration={
markings,% switch on markings
mark=at position -0.001cm with {\arrow[red,very thick]{>}},
mark=at position 1.1pt with {\arrow[red,very thick]{Bracket[]}}
},shorten >=1.2pt] (1,0) -- (3,0); % better looking but not self-adapting to different marking sizes
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Two solutions, none perfect:

- on the second line the bracket is now a bit too much on the left to my taste, and the segment's square corners now slightly protrude out of the tip.
- on the third line, it looks good but it will not self-adapt if you change the decoration's size

[image]

Comment: You can fix the position by changing mark=at position 0cm into mark=at position 1cm another length but that trick won't adapt itself if you change the size of the markings.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions